# Barchsrt series donot show data when I change series name and data provider?

Tags: actionscript-3, data-binding, mxml, dataprovider, arraycollection

I create my bar chart as following:
     
            
                
            
            
                
            
            
                
                    {axisStroke}
                    {axisStroke}
                    {axisStroke}

```
        <!-- horizontal axis -->
        <mx:horizontalAxis>
            <mx:LinearAxis id="ac" baseAtZero="true"/>
        </mx:horizontalAxis>
        <!-- horizontal axis renderer -->
        <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
            <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{ac}" 
                             canDropLabels="true" 
                             styleName="wsViewAxisLabel"
                             minorTickPlacement="none" 
                             tickPlacement="none" 
                             labelGap="0" 
                             showLabels="false" 
                             showLine="false">
                <mx:axisStroke>{axisStroke}</mx:axisStroke>
                <mx:tickStroke>{axisStroke}</mx:tickStroke>
                <mx:minorTickStroke>{axisStroke}</mx:minorTickStroke>
            </mx:AxisRenderer>
        </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
        <mx:series>
            <mx:BarSeries id="barSeries" color="#FFFFFF" labelAlign="right"
                          displayName="{seriesName}"
                          filters="{[new DropShadowFilter(2,45,0,.3)]}" fontSize="11"
                          fontWeight="bold" labelField="{valueName}"
                          xField="{seriesName}"
                          showDataEffect="{interpolateIn}"
                          yField="{categoryName}">
                <mx:fill>
                    <mx:LinearGradient id="linearGradient">
                        <mx:entries>
                            <fx:Array>
                                <mx:GradientEntry color="0x99ffcc"
                                                  ratio="0.0"
                                                  alpha="0.1" />
                                <mx:GradientEntry color="0x99ffcc"
                                                  ratio="1.0"
                                                  alpha="1.0"/>
                            </fx:Array>
                        </mx:entries>
                    </mx:LinearGradient>
                </mx:fill>
            </mx:BarSeries>
        </mx:series>
        <mx:annotationElements>
            <mx:CartesianDataCanvas id="mCanvas"/>
        </mx:annotationElements>
    </mx:BarChart>
```

but when I change the series name and datacollection. the bar chart did not show data.

I try to debug code and find the barseries's items length is 0. it's dataprovider and series name, xfield, yfield is right. do not know why barseries did not create barseriesitems.

many thanks for help.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `dataProvider` is bound to the original name, so the `dataProvider` assignment to the ID needs to be updated. The `dataProvider` is bound the the `ArrayCollection`, so the `ArrayCollection` assignment to the `dataProvider` needs to be updated as well.

**References**

- [Flex Mobile Performance Checklist](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex-mobile-performance-checklist.html)